# Can I use a Class object as a DataMember?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

This is the class need to serialized.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Fullresponse
    {
        [DataMember(Order=0)]
        public string success { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string participants { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string term { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public categoryCollection categories { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string total { get; set; }



    }
```

This is categoryCollection Class

```
[DataContract]
    public class categoryCollection
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Results online { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Results offline { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is result class

```
public class Results
    {
        public string categoryName { get; set; }


        public List<Node> results { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get Fullresponse class object from WCF service to my client app.
How Can I achieve this. From this code it is give an error. When I remove categoryCollection object from Fullresponse class it works fine.

This is my Service web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
      switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
      propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "c:\log\TracesTest1.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And This is my Client app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:23894/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

stack trace of error..

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowHttpProtocolException(String
>   message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, String statusDescription)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ValidateContentType()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage
>   httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback
>   asynCallback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor
>   acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor
>   replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext
>   context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object
>   state)
>   System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Client Side Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Service1Client clirnt = new Service1Client();
            Fullresponse C = new Fullresponse();
            C = clirnt.GetDataUsingDataContractnew("","");


        }
```

IService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(int id);

        [OperationContract]
        Fullresponse GetDataUsingDataContractnew(string id, string skey);
        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
  public class Service1 : IService1
     {
         public string GetData(int value)
         {
             return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
         }

         public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(int id)
         {
             CompositeType ct = new CompositeType();
             return ct;
         }

         public Fullresponse GetDataUsingDataContractnew(string id,string skey)
         {
             Fullresponse fr = new Fullresponse();
             SearchContacts sr = new SearchContacts();
             fr = sr.GetJson(id, skey);
             return fr;
         }
     }

getJson method

     public Fullresponse GetJson(string id, string skey)
            {
                List<Node> on = new List<Node>();
                List<Node> off = new List<Node>();
                Results Online = new Results();
                Results Offline = new Results();

                on.Add(new Contact("on1", "url1", "des1", "aaa"));
                off.Add(new Contact("off2", "url2", "des2", "bbb"));
                Online.categoryName = "Online";
                Online.results = on;
                Offline.categoryName = "Offline";
                Offline.results = off;
                categoryCollection categoryCollection = new categoryCollection();
                categoryCollection.online = Online;
                categoryCollection.offline = Offline;

                Fullresponse searchCon = new Fullresponse();
                searchCon.success = "true";
                searchCon.term = "a";
                searchCon.categories = categoryCollection;
                searchCon.total = "1";

                return searchCon;

            }
```

Node Class

```
 [DataContract]
    public abstract class Node
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string description { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
        public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
        public virtual void AddComment()
        {

        }
        public virtual void AddContact()
        {

        }
    }
```

Action Class

```
 [DataContract]
    public class Action
    {
        public Action() { }
        public Action(string icon, string url)
        {
            this.icon = icon;
            this.url = url;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string icon { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

Please Help me to solve this.

Comment: Could you please add some more details about the error you are getting? My guess is the problem is your Results class, I'm not sure how a List<Object> would be serialized.

Comment: check these 2 links it will answer your question
 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have traced the error.

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `DataContract` to  `Results` class as well.

`DataContractSerializer` is an opt-in serializer, meaning *it would serialize only what you tell serializer to serialize*. Since you have not marked the `Results` class with `DataContract` attribute, it wouldn't be serialized.

All .NET Framework primitive types, such as `Byte, SByte, Int16, Int32, Int64, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, Single, Double, Boolean, Char, Decimal, Object, and String` can be serialized with no other preparation and are considered as having default data contracts.

For more information on Types Supported by DataContractSerializer read [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[DataContract]
public class Results
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string categoryName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Object> results { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I did This change to Result class but error is still there.

Error is:

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Comment: You need to make sure that `Client` and `Service` side use the **same** bindings. If client is using `BasicHttpBinding` then make sure server also has `BasicHttpBinding`.

Comment: i have added config files. Can you please check them?
thank You.

Comment: Try changing scheme from https to http in Service config `<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>`

Comment: Also, can you post the code for method and how are you consuming the service in client.

Comment: In the posted code, there is no code for Node class. However, removing that part from code and can run the code without error. I would suggest you to use `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"`, this would give the exception details and hence help to solve the error.

Comment: I have Added Node Class

Comment: Thanks For the great Support

Answer (score 0):

I Solve This problem like follows.

```
[KnownType(typeof(Contact)), KnownType(typeof(Apps)), KnownType(typeof(Person))]
    [DataContract]
    public abstract class Node
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string description { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
        public virtual void AddComment()
        {

        }
        public virtual void AddContact()
        {

        }
    }
```

by adding `KnownType()`

thnaks All for the support